# Memory Managing recursive parents - Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm having some trouble resolving some rather scary memory leaks the Memory Leaks tools is showing me when I run my iOS application.

I have a Path object that contains a parent variable of the same class, and that parent contains its own parent and so on.

What I want to do is give another object a deep copy of this object, it can then do what ever it likes with that copy and it should have no affect on the original.

I think the problem lies with when I make a copy of my Object like so:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    ShortestPathStep *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithSteps:self];

    return copy;
}
```

This calls my copy constructer:

```
-(id)initWithSteps:(ShortestPathStep*)copyFrom
{
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
        position = copyFrom.position;
        gScore = copyFrom.gScore;
        hScore = copyFrom.hScore;
        parent = [copyFrom.parent copy];
    }

    return self;
}
```

I've also tried releasing the parent in the dealloc method, like so:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    if(parent != nil)
        [parent release];

    [super dealloc]; }
```

However this gives me the following error message:

malloc: *** error for object 0x12df1810: pointer being freed was not allocated

How should I handle the memory that I am allocating when copying this pointer?

And is this producing a deep copy, including a deep copy of the parent variable? Some exceptions I have been getting suggest either pointers I don't want are being cleaned up or they are being reassigned in other areas of my code.

EDIT:
To resolve my exception in the dealloc method I have changed the property in the .h file to:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ShortestPathStep *parent;
```

Comment: why dont you normally release this memory at dealloc? it seems that i dont get your issue, please try to explain :)

Comment: I've added what happens when I try to release the memory in the dealloc method, it gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some general notes

Make sure that `position`, `gScore` and `hScore` are retain properties properties
for parent, make the property to be of type copy

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) Your_Parent parent;
```

Update your init function to

```
-(id)initWithSteps:(ShortestPathStep*)copyFrom
{
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
        self.position = copyFrom.position;
        self.gScore = copyFrom.gScore;
        self.hScore = copyFrom.hScore;
        self.parent = copyFrom.parent;
    }

    return self;
}
```

now the release in dealloc should work.

Comment: That left me with the same exception, but I have managed to resolve that by setting the property to retain.  I think that should resolve my memory leaks.